# Trying to remove NLog.config results in "Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nlog

I have been moving the content of `NLog.config` to my `App.config` and was about to delete the original nlog configuration file.

However `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.8.4)` prevents me from doing so with the following error message:

> Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file.
>   C:......csproj.nuget.g.props

When opening the aforementioned file I find the following section:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
<None Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)nlog.config\4.5.10\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)nlog.config\4.5.10\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config')">
  <NuGetPackageId>NLog.Config</NuGetPackageId>
  <NuGetPackageVersion>4.5.10</NuGetPackageVersion>
  <NuGetItemType>None</NuGetItemType>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <TargetPath>NLog.config</TargetPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Link>NLog.config</Link>
</None>
```

After deleting the section `<ItemGroup>` the `NLog.config` was gone, but came up again with autogenerated default content.

So long story short: How can I delete the file `NLog.config` at the root of my project when I have moved all the configuration stuff to `App.config`

Comment: Looks like a NuGet thing. You might have to delete the package and find one that does not setup the config file and just installs the DLL's.

Comment: Ha, sweat, thanks for that hint, Post it as answer and I will accept it. Removing Replacing the package `NLog.Config` with `NLog` did the trick...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a NuGet thing. You might have to delete the package and find one that does not setup the config file and just installs the DLL's.

Per @matze

Removing Replacing the package NLog.Config with NLog did the trick